# Continuously send data during Python For Loop when condition met in Flask

Tags: python, html, opencv, flask

I can't seem to send a request containing text during video feed capture loop using OpenCv to the web app in order to show this text in a container.

While the video feed is displayed on the web app, during this loop, once a certain condition is met, I want to send a request containing text where this text will be displayed in the web app under the video feed and will frequently when condition is met as seen below.

```
def show_feed():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    frame_list = []
    rand_val = random.randrange(1, 20) # Random value
    while True:
        _, frame = cap.read()
        frame_list.append(frame)
        if len(frame_list) == rand_val:
            send_text = f"Frame {str(rand_val)}/{str(len(frame_list))" # "Frame 2/20"

            ### HERE ###
            ### send request to web app containg this text to web app displaying in text box
            ### HERE ###
            time.sleep(5)
            frame_list = []
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
            b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame.tobytes() + b'\r\n')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(show_feed(),
    mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Where the html is as follows:

```
<!-- html stuff-->

<body>
    <div class="video">
         <img src="{{ url_for('video_feed') }}"/>
    <div class="container">
        <input type="text" id="textbox"/> <!-- display text here met output frame from python For Loop ->>
</body>

<!-- html stuff-->
```

Comment: Add a js script which will continuously send xhr requests to some path until receive some stop signal.

Comment: @OlvinRoght How would this be done in the `show_feed()` function that would be able to send a request that can be caught through a script tag in html? I've tried various methods with no success.

Comment: It can't be done in `show_feed()` function. You need to declare one more path which will return content you want to return. Also you need to add js script to your template which will send xhr request to this specific path.